# How do I start a long-living background task?

Tags: multithreading, windows-phone-7, background

i write a Demo App in WP7, the App has 2 Counter, the second counter should work 
in background even if the App is Closed. 
Like background work in iOS:
`beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` 
or Services in Android.

thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is not a direct equivalent to Android services or iOS's `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler` (which are different from each other) in WP7.

A [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) ([sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)) is most closely related to Android's AsyncTask and runs  background code while the application is running.

Alternatively you can register a [`ScheduledTaskAgent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.scheduler.scheduledtaskagent%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) ([overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), [sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202941%28v=VS.92%29.aspx), [best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202944%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)) to run in small, 15 second bursts every 30 minutes or so (though it's not guaranteed to run at all if the phone is low on power).

I guess a better question would be: could you not just record the time at which the application moved into the background and then update your counter as appropriate when the application is relaunched?

Comment: +1 for suggesting a solution following the Windows Phone Application Lifecycle concept :)